# Python wait for all forked processes to finish

Tags: python, fork

My python code creates a huge hash table (60GB+) on which a number of heavy readonly operations are to be performed. To speed things up I fork the process a few dozen times once the hash table has been created so that each operation can be done concurrently (48-core machine).

Once all these forked children are done with their thing I wish to merge their output, so I need a way for the parent process to be able to wait for more than one pid. How do I achieve that?

Forking is a key part here as I rely on the forked processes' memory pages being mapped to the parent's address space to reduce footprint. The hash table is being created by another library so modifying its implementation isn't an option.

```
children = []
for index in batch:
    tracks = batch[index]
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        # forked process
        run_batch(tracks, index)
    else:
        # main process
        children.append(pid)
        print('spawned child ', pid)
```

Comment: simply use `os.wait`.

Comment: @Daniel it doesn't work. `os.wait` waits for only one process, I have at least 12.

Comment: Doesn't relay on the order. Please, describe, why you cannot use `wait`.

Comment: @Daniel If you use wait in a while loop until all children have exited then it will work as suggested in that answer. But I still think the code posted relies on a particular order. The for loop won't proceed without each `waitpid` call returning. Anyway that answer still solved my problem so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I got the problem wrong, but I see two simple solutions:

If you know beforehand, how many operations there will be in total, you could combine writing in your table with augmenting a counter. Your merge function would sleep until the counter reaches a certain number.

Another and maybe cleaner way would be using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

First you would need to [group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) the operations, that you need parallelized and then [chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) the group with the merging function.

This would result in all tasks inside your group being processed in parallel as the first part of the chain, and only when all tasks in the group are done, the second part of your chain, the merge, is activated.

Comment: Seems like you really got the problem wrong. Children are forked once the hash table has been completely written. Also they need to be forked so as to avoid using 60GB per process, celery doesn't do that.